# Testing a simple polygon for monotonicity in linear time question

Tags: algorithms, geometry

I'm looking for the algorithm of Preparata and Supowit for testing a simple polygon for monotonicity in linear time.
I've found it referenced in many textbooks but I can't find the algorithm itself.

Here's the information on the original article:

http://md1.csa.com/partners/viewrecord.php?requester=gs&collection=TRD&recid=0164490CI

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're just looking for a link to the actual article? If so, it can be found [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020019081900910). It is unfortunately behind a pay wall, so I hope that your university has access.

Comment: I'm looking for a pseudo-code or a description of the algorithm: when you search for dijkstra shortest paths on the internet there are plenty of sites with such an information. At least, what is the general idea of the algorithm: is it some sweep line rotating around an axis, or something based on clever lemmas and ad hoc geometric manipulations etc..

Comment: In all seriousness, isn't the paper the best place to go for that?

Comment: I don't have access to the paper. Most if not all algorithms I see in textbooks are explained. No luck for this one: it's mentioned in the books - ".. there is a way to do it in linear time ...", then, for example, the actual algorithm for triangulating a monotone polygon is given, but it's kind of useless if I can't perform the test.
Until now, I've found a paper which is publicly available and contains two lemmas from the original paper, and I'll try to reconstruct the algorithm from them.